# How to get modify information of a renamed file in a specific commit?

Tags: git

I want to get the modify information of a particular file(file_path) in a particular commit(commit_id). I know I can use `git show commit_id file_path` to achieve. But this method cannot handle the case when the file was renamed after that commit.
For example, gr was renamed to gr1 in this commit.
[image]

So if I use `git show --follow da2727b4556e19b873911ffaa6ae10043bb78715 gr1`, there's no output. And if I use gr, git cannot find the path.
[image]

Now I can only use `git show --follow da2727b4556e19b873911ffaa6ae10043bb78715` to get modify information of all changed files in that commit. I wonder if there's a method to get modify information of the particular renamed file? Thank you！

Comment: `git show --follow commit -- path` try adding 2 dashes before the path .

Comment: @Dev-vruper I tried that but it didn't seem to work (return nothing). But `git diff` worked.

Comment: The `--follow` flag makes no sense in `git show`, which only looks at one commit-diff. (In `git log`, `--follow` means: after you have looked at this diff, *change the file name* for the next commit you look at. Since `git show` does not look at a next commit, there's no point in `--follow` here.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `git show` (tried it), but I managed to get it to work with `git diff` on one of my repos with multiple edits in a commit. For it to work for you try:

`git diff da2727b4556e19b873911ffaa6ae10043bb78715 -- gr`

Note the double-hyphens before the list of files, and you must provide the full path working tree.

Comment: This also works with `git show`. The general rule here is that diff-generating commands allow pathspecs; if a name like `gr` might be ambiguous (might be a revision *or* a path), prefixing it with `--` makes Git treat it as a path.